# Install Xvfb via yum - yum repository for Xvfb?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, installation

I am trying to install Xvfb on a RHEL 6.2 system using yum.  However, all of the help that I've found says to type:

```
    yum install Xvfb
```

or...

```
    yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

Which I'm sure would work if I had the correct repo configured, which I'm guessing I don't.  Because I get the error:

```
    No package Xvfb available.
```

The only repos I have on this system are redhat.repo and rhel-source.repo.  Which repo contains the Xvfb package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Umm, the package is called "xorg-x11-server-Xvfb" on CentOS5.

So you should be using the second option, "yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb".  You can do "yum search xvfb" which gives you the proper name of the package, also.

Comment: Tried both of those, neither work.  Search returns no matching packages, and "yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb" tells me "No package xorg-x11-server-Xvfb available".

Comment: xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.i386 on my RHEL 5.5 machine.. Wonder if they axed it in 6.0

Comment: Weird.  It's a standard RHEL package.  Maybe run "yum clean" to clear out local data?  This might be something you get to bug RH about.

Comment: @Tim.  On CentOS6.2, I see "xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.i686 0:1.10.4-6.el6_2.1" so it's derived from standard RHEL sources.  It's also mentioned on this official RH doc: http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2011-1816.html so it should be available from RedHat.  This sounds more like an issue with Torgis's  yum configuration.

Comment: Could very well be. I tried yum clean all, yum search all xvfb and get nothing.  Which repos do you have added in /etc/yum.repos.d?  I just looked at my redhat repo and it's blank.  That's likely not good.

Comment: You might be correct, his output `No package Xvfb available.` sounds like his shell isn't escaping the hyphens or something, I would expect something along the lines of `No package xorg-x11-server-Xvfb available.`

Comment: @torgis Is your subscription dead?

Comment: I not running RedHat, so I'm not sure, but I'm pretty sure redhat.repo should not be blank.

Comment: My `epel.repo` file is not blank.

Comment: Someone else built this system for me, I have SSH access from 1200 miles away.  The subscription thing might be key, I see this:  "This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled."

Comment: Yup, that will stop your system from pulling rpms from epel. I don't know if there is a non-subscription version of the epel available.

Comment: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Answer (score 7):

Enable the optional content repositories by editing /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo .

Open the file search for optional - change enabled=0 to enabled=1

```
[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (RPMs)
mirrorlist=https://rhui2-cds01.REGION.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/mirror/content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/optional/os

enabled=1
```

This should work.

Comment: I used `sudo yum install --enablerepo rhel-7-server-optional-rpms xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`.  Just a different way to achieve what @Aamreeta suggests here (without editing the yum.repos.d/redhat.repo file).

Answer (score 4):

It's available on the Client, Workstation, and Server Optional Channels inside RHN:
(Note the URLs here will prompt for your redhat support account)

https://rhn.redhat.com/network/software/packages/name_overview.pxt?package_name=xorg-x11-server-Xvfb&archIdList=&archLabelList=&search_subscribed_channels=yes

You'll need to configure the appropriate entitlement in order to use one of those channels with your system, of course.

You can search for packages at the following URL if you're not familiar with (or don't like) the Package Kit gui or the equivalent yum functionality:

https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/channels/software/Search.do

cheers!

Comment: Silly question as a follow-up...once I have a support account, where do I put that information on my system so that these yum repositories will work?

Comment: your link gives me anything... I believe that it doesn't work anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for explaining the solution...for some reason the ftp link for me was malformed and so I was getting errors such as...

```
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/beta/6Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml:[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 9 - "Server denied you to change to the given directory"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhel-beta. Please verify its path and try again
```

Notice the "6Server" part, that directory doesn't exist or something is wrong with what I was doing.

Anyway, I ended up replacing $releasever for now with "6"
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/beta/6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml

and from what I can tell the "sudo yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb" install it fine

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

works in CentOS 7

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figured it out.  The answer is to add the rhel-beta repository, thus bypassing the need for an RHN subscription:

```
[rhel-beta]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta - $basearch
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/beta/$releasever/$basearch/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta-2
priority=1
exclude=*release

[rhel-beta-optional]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta (Optional) - $basearch
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/beta/$releasever/optional/$basearch/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta-2
priority=1
exclude=*release
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: where are you supposed to put this configuration?

Comment: it did not work.